# Force .NET UTF-8 encoder to output 3-byte encoded characters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, utf-8, utf

I am working on a foreign file format that was apparently developed in Japan. Most of their strings are stored with UTF-8 encoding in the 3-byte format (i.e. the capital A is represented as 0xEF,0xBC,0xA1). While it is no problem to decode such strings in .NET, I could not find a way to force the framework to output in the same format, as it will default to the abbreviated form (makes sense, but really I do need the 3-byte form).

Is there any standard functionality that will take care of this? Me being lazy I do not want to implement it myself :)

Comment: It already does - that's the *definition* of UTF8, using 1 or more bytes to emit Unicode characters. UTF8 is a variable-length encoding.. What code did you try, what was the problem? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It doesn’t already encode A as EF BC A1.

Comment: `the capital A is represented as 0xEF,0xBC,0xA1` no it's not. This page is UTF8, like almost all web sites these days. Check the source, save it to disk and check the bytes. None of the English characters is saved as multiple bytes

Comment: @Ry it shouldn't. That's not UTF8

Comment: UTF8 is very specific, and 3 bytes for A isn't it. UTF16 or UTF32 aren't that either. So what encoding is this question about? It's one thing if it's an obscure Unicode encoding we could search for, or may be available through its codepage number,  another thing entirely if it's a completely custom encoding

Comment: Your code is about `FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A`. This is a Japanese specialty to write Latin characters. Do not use it as standard `A` letter, but when you need full-width. Because Japanese (and Chinese) characters are large, usually we put two latin characters in one "place", but for some titles or vertical layout.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: stop disinformation: "None of the English characters is saved as multiple bytes". This is completely wrong. Good English needs more then 7-bit ASCII characters (these were choose just as subset of most useful characters in telco context). Good English writing requires also some typography knowledge, and good English requires also many diacritics in names.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the letter `'A'`. It's a different rune, the [FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff21/index.htm). Notice the extra spacing in `'Ａ'`.

This isn't a different UTF8 format, it's a different character. Whoever produced this kind of file either made a mistake, or intentionally used those glyphs for layout purposes.

If you want to produce a similar text, you'll have to find how those characters are used in the first place, eg. for some words, every word, specific sections? Then you'll have to modify your own text to match this, eg by replacing normal letters with the full-width equivalents.

You can convert such strings with [String.Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Normalize_System_Text_NormalizationForm_), using the KC or KD normalisation forms. For example, the following expression :

```
"'ＡA'".Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKC)
```

Returns:

```
'AA'
```

Comment: thanks, that was informative. however: if it is a different character then, is there any way to convert the other way around? i.e. if i wanna go from the standard 'A' to 'Ａ'?
i tried the normalization functions, but they will just go from 'Ａ' to 'A', which is not what i need if i want to write some edited text back to the file...